# how to jump back to a branch statement?

Tags: arrays, assembly, return, mips, mars-simulator

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to implement this in the Mips/Mars architecture.

I'm making a Battleship game and storing the board as an array that can hold 100 ints.

I need to loop through the player's array and convert the information stored in each 'cell' to graphical data for the purpose of displaying the board to the user.

My troubles stem from the fact that the characters being displayed to the user are based on what values are in each cell of the array.

If the value is 0 (empty) - print '[ ]', if 1 (guessed and empty) print - '[O]', and if 2 (guessed and hit) print - '[X]'.

So as I'm looping through each cell in the array, I need to check the value and branch to the appropriate print function.

My problem is that if I branch to the print statement, how do I jump back to where the branch statement was?

Pseudo code:

```
Looping through array, 'ArrayCell' = value at current array location
branch if equal ArrayCell, 0, print empty
branch if equal ArrayCell, 1, print miss
branch if equal ArrayCell, 2, print hit
increment array

print empty:
print then jump back to loop
print miss:
print then jump back to loop
print hit:
print then jump back to loop
```

How do you jump back to the branch statement after printing to preserve where you are in the array?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 2):

Put a label above the `increment array` operator and at the end of `print empty`, `print miss`, and `print hit`, `j` to the label.

Example:

```
   Looping through array, 'ArrayCell' = value at current array location
    branch if equal ArrayCell, 0, print empty
    branch if equal ArrayCell, 1, print miss
    branch if equal ArrayCell, 2, print hit

   LBL_Increment:
    increment array

   loop


    print empty:
    print
    j LBL_Increment
    print miss:
    print
    j LBL_Increment
    print hit:
    print
    j LBL_Increment
```

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry, I'm very new to this and feel like ripping my hair out.

Thanks a lot! I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using [function calls](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa06/cs232/lectures/L3.ppt) for this.

```
   Looping through array, 'ArrayCell' = value at current array location
    if equal ArrayCell, 0, JAL empty
    if equal ArrayCell, 1, JAL miss
    if equal ArrayCell, 2, JAL hit

   LBL_Increment:
    increment array

   loop


   empty:
    print " "
    JR $RA    // return to the instruction after the "JAL empty" instruction.
   miss:
    print "miss"
    JR $RA
   hit:
    print "hit"
    JR $RA
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The other one could end up leading you to what was called spaghetti code.